# Get rid of Another update is currently in progress

Tags: updates

I was trying to update my wordpress core to 4.5.1 but my system was missing some permissions, and now after giving correct permission, I cannot get rid of that message and I cannot upgrade.
Tried to look for a .maintainance file but there is not.

How do I update now?

Thanks for help

Comment: That message got auto removed after a few minutes, so the problem is now solved an I successfully updated my wordpress installation

Comment: It could be due to some cache (ex: WP Object Cache) that may have cleared itself after a few minutes.

Comment: Add your comment as an answer and mark as complete to close it out. Glad you got it working.

Comment: provided you a little tip at the end `$>wp option delete my_option`

Comment: Just "select SELECT * FROM `wp_options` WHERE `option_name` LIKE '%core_update%'" from your db.
Just delete this row "delete core_updater.lock" from wp_options table and run it again. It helps

Comment: None of the answers work in Wordpress 4.9. Here's what works instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34929245/wordpress-cant-write-to-db-after-migration

Answer (score 126):

It is an automatic lock to prevent simultaneous core updates. It will be gone after 15 minutes. If you don't want to wait, delete the record from options table – usually `wp_options`.

Since Wordpress 4.5:

```
option_name = 'core_updater.lock'
```

If you have an **older** installation (before Wordpress 4.5):

```
option_name = 'core_updater'
```

Comment: In my installation there is no such row in database and the message still appears. The real option name is `core_updater.lock` (for Wordpress 4.5.3)

Comment: BEST IDEA: Do this with WP CLI: `wp option delete core_updater.lock`

Comment: I am not finding either 1 of these in the wp_options table, and still getting this message.

Comment: I don't have anything like this in wp database

Comment: nothing can be found like this at my database, not `core_updater.lock` and not even `core_updater`

Comment: @Athlan and where to find it? I have 4.9.7 and can't find such options in my database

Comment: @user924 here https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/da7a80d67fea29c2badfc538bfc01c8a585f0cbe/wp-admin/includes/class-core-upgrader.php#L119.

Comment: Most probably wp_option table doesn't have option_id field as auto increment

Answer (score 29):

If you use wp-cli run the following command:

```
wp option delete core_updater.lock
```

This command will delete the option named: `core_updater.lock`

Comment: doesn't help WordPress 4.9.7

Comment: this option still works in WP 5+

Comment: Yes, It does. It will work on any latest version

Comment: @user924 if this doesn't resolve the issue, please check the wp_options table has auto_increment enabled for the option_id field.

Answer (score 9):

Add this code to any plugin or your theme's **functions.php** file. Remember to remove it when you're done to prevent flicking your database for no reason.

```
delete_option( "core_updater.lock" );
```

Comment: doesn't help WordPress 4.9.7

Comment: this is still available in WP 5+

Comment: I am not aware of anything in 4.9.7 that makes this not work, despite user924's comment.

Answer (score 1):

Per @jeremyclarke, running this at the terminal resolved this issue for me:
`wp option delete core_updater.lock`

Comment: doesn't help WordPress 4.9.7

Answer (score 0):

Confirming this `'core_updater.lock'`. It may not be obvious at first but look at the line `771`.

```
File: wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php
754:    /**
755:     * Creates a lock using WordPress options.
756:     *
757:     * @since 4.5.0
758:     * @access public
759:     * @static
760:     *
761:     * @param string $lock_name       The name of this unique lock.
762:     * @param int    $release_timeout Optional. The duration in seconds to respect an existing lock.
763:     *                                Default: 1 hour.
764:     * @return bool False if a lock couldn't be created or if the lock is no longer valid. True otherwise.
765:     */
766:    public static function create_lock( $lock_name, $release_timeout = null ) {
767:        global $wpdb;
768:        if ( ! $release_timeout ) {
769:            $release_timeout = HOUR_IN_SECONDS;
770:        }
771:        $lock_option = $lock_name . '.lock';
772: 
773:        // Try to lock.
774:        $lock_result = $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "INSERT IGNORE INTO `$wpdb->options` ( `option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload` ) VALUES (%s, %s, 'no') /* LOCK */", $lock_option, time() ) );
775:
```

Now, if you like you may [delete](http://wp-cli.org/commands/option/) this option:

```
$>wp option delete core_updater.lock
```

Comment: doesn't help WordPress 4.9.7

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for the full MySQL query:

`DELETE FROM wp_options WHERE option_name LIKE '%core_update%' LIMIT 1`

Comment: Perhaps `WHERE option_name = 'core_updater.lock'` to directly specify the right option.

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress there are two update locks:

- core_updater
- auto_updater

So, you can fix this by deleting the update locks.

Use below code to delete the lock's:

```
delete_option( 'core_updater.lock' );
delete_option( 'auto_updater.lock' );
```

You can delete the update locks with CLI command too. Checkout how to [delete them with CLI](https://wp.me/p4Ams0-15y) command.

Use the WordPress plugin[enter link description here](https://i2.wp.com/maheshwaghmare.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/fix-wordpress-another-update-is-currently-in-progress.png?resize=1024%2C493&ssl=1) 
[fix-update-in-process](https://wordpress.org/plugins/fix-update-in-process/) which show the existing locks and fix the issue with one click.