# How To Fix the “Another Update is Currently in Progress” Error in WordPress

Tags: customization

How To Fix the “Another Update is Currently in Progress” Error in WordPress what are the quick ways to fix the error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get rid of Another update is currently in progress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/224989/get-rid-of-another-update-is-currently-in-progress)

Answer (score -1):

Whenever WordPress breaks, it can be frustrating to try to figure out what's causing the issue. It's even more frustrating when you can't access important parts of your site for hours.
Here are a few suggestions on how to fix this problem.

**Method No-1 Use a Plugin**

**Step-1 Go To WordPress Dashboard**
Then Go To Add New Plugins
Search Forfix another update in progress”
Once you activate it, you’ll see a new menu under Settings labeled Fix Another Update In Progress.
If it detects the lock in your database, it will show this screen. Just click the Fix WordPress Update Lock button and the database entry should be instantly removed.

**Method No-2  Use Php Admin**
Access PhP admin through Cpanel
On the left menu with several drop-downs, open your site’s database and select wp_options.
Once you click through to wp_options, you should see a table of various database entries. You may see it right in the list, or your table may be far too large. If you can’t find it, use the Filter rows bar above the table and enter “core_updater.lock” to jump right to it.

Now just click Delete on the “core_updater.lock” row.
With that, you’re free to go back to WordPress and update your site again.

These are the methods to To Fix the “Another Update is Currently in Progress” Error in WordPress